# Why was Hogwarts chosen to host the Triwizard tournament?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, albus-dumbledore

I'm looking for canon for what the process was that chose Hogwarts to host the Triwizard Tournament after its reinstatement in GoF.  Anything JKR said, preferably.

Comment: Because Harry couldn't have been a Champion otherwise!

Answer (score 8):

According to *Goblet of Fire*, the tournament host rotates between the three major Wizarding schools: Beauxbatons Academy of Magic, Durmstrang Institute, and Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry.

These three host schools were chosen because, as the primary source of Wizarding education in Europe, a friendly rivalry had built up between them. (No mention is made why the Wizarding Schools from other continents didn't participate, though obviously it would no longer be the *Tri*Wizard Tournament.)

When the Tournament was revived during the 1994/95 school year, it was Hogwarts turn to host it, so they hosted it.